# formatting the seeds file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seed

I'm modifying a seed file for a site that is already in existence.

One of the fields in the table I'm changing is a text area.

I would like to format the information I am inputting in the seed file so I don't have to go back and change it manually on the site.

Currently an entry in the seed file looks like this

```
if !Store.exists?(:title => 'store Cavan')
Store.create(
    opening_hours: 'Mon. to Fri.     8:30 - 9:00PM
                    Saturday         8:30 - 7:00 PM
                    Sunday         11:00 - 7:00 PM',
    latitude: 53,
    longitude: -7,
    title: 'test store Cavan',
    street_line_one: 'test Retail Park',
    street_line_two: 'test Road',
    town: 'Cavan',
    county: 'Cavan',
    country: 'Ireland')
```

When I run rake db:seed this comes out in an info box like this

```
Mon. to Fri.     8:30 - 9:00PMSaturday         8:30 - 7:00 PMSunday         11:00 - 7:00 PM
```

Instead of this

```
Mon. to Fri.     8:30 - 9:00PM
Saturday         8:30 - 7:00 PM
Sunday         11:00 - 7:00 PM
```

I have tried add in '\n' in there and "\n" but that breaks my site. I know this is only a small issue but I would like to know how to keep some sort of formatting when I run my seeds, in this case a new line after each time is displayed.

any help is very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: use [Store#find_or_create_by](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) instead `!Store.exists?`

Comment: no, i want to wipe all the data first

Comment: use `\n` but make sure you use double quotes, not single quotes around the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\n` would definitely work. I am not sure how you used `\n` and it didn't work out for you. 
Change your `create` method call by including `\n` as below:

```
Store.create(
    opening_hours: 'Mon. to Fri.     8:30 - 9:00PM\nSaturday         8:30 - 7:00 PM\nSunday         11:00 - 7:00 PM',
    latitude: 53,
    longitude: -7,
    title: 'test store Cavan',
    street_line_one: 'test Retail Park',
    street_line_two: 'test Road',
    town: 'Cavan',
    county: 'Cavan',
    country: 'Ireland')
```

**UPDATE**

As per the chat session. OP opted for adding the code in its entirety in html to the seed file to get the correct format.

Comment: have done this exact thing and still not working at all.
just pus \n in the text

Comment: What error do you get? I just tried it on my application and it works. If you want to discuss this on chat then join me http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Comment: Thanks, since the display area was html_safe the initial seed data could be inserted directly as html

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this with heredoc:

```
opening_hours = <<-END.gsub(/^\s*/, '')
  Mon. to Fri.     8:30 - 9:00 PM
  Saturday         8:30 - 7:00 PM
  Sunday          11:00 - 7:00 PM
END
=> "Mon. to Fri.     8:30 - 9:00 PM\nSaturday         8:30 - 7:00 PM\nSunday          11:00 - 7:00 PM\n"
```

You can use any method you like after the opening `END`, e.g. [ruby-dedent](https://github.com/cespare/ruby-dedent) to remove the indent (in case you don't like regular expressions). The closing `END` doesn't have to be at the beginning of the line, the `-` in front of the opening `END` means, all whitespace in front of the closing `END` shall be ignored.

In your case:

```
Store.create(
  latitude: 53,
  longitude: -7,
  title: 'test store Cavan',
  street_line_one: 'test Retail Park',
  street_line_two: 'test Road',
  town: 'Cavan',
  county: 'Cavan',
  country: 'Ireland',
  opening_hours: <<-END.strip_heredoc
    Mon. to Fri.     8:30 - 9:00 PM
    Saturday         8:30 - 7:00 PM
    Sunday          11:00 - 7:00 PM
  END
)
```

The `strip_heredoc` comes with ActiveSupport and yields the same result here as the `gsub`.

The heredoc has to be the last attribute assigned because to my knowledge, there's no way to have the closing `END` and a comma on the same line.

Heredocs are just a very nice way to embed formatted data in source code - and Ruby has particularly great support for it. Google it!

Comment: So I don't fully follow, in this example are you creating a method in the seed file and then calling it at each instance of opening_hours: ?

Comment: No, I'm just assigning a value to a variable opening_hours - for simplicity's sake. I'll update the anwer with your case.

Comment: Heredocs are a matter of taste, but personally, I don't like oversize strings with whitespace in them. I prefer formatted text to be formatted in the source file as well.